# Buenas prácticas al definir IQueryable

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Al trabajar con `IQueryable` y luego materializando las listas utilizando Entity Framework he obtenido resultados con tiempos muy variados modificando la forma de filtrar y el orden de las entidades, las mejoras han sido a prueba y error.

¿Alguien sabe las buenas prácticas para definir `IQueryable`?

Comment: Sugiero para el que intente responder esta pregunta que cree un community wiki para que todos puedan incluir las posibles buenas prácticas en una sola respuesta. No tiene sentido que las recomendaciones estén divididas en varias respuestas y solo una sea la aceptada.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que consejaria es que analices algunos puntos de rendimiento cuando defines las queries
[Consideraciones de rendimiento para Entity Framework 5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/data/hh949853.aspx)

Podrias evaluar la pregeneracion de vistas, estas tienen un costo elevando en la performance
[Consideraciones de rendimiento (Entity Framework)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/cc853327(v=vs.110).aspx)

Tambien es importante hacer uso del Include() cuando quiere recuperar datos relacionados
[Eager loading en Entity Framework: mejora drástica del rendimiento en acceso a datos](http://www.variablenotfound.com/2013/05/eager-loading-en-entity-framework.html)

Segun la operacion que realices desabilitar la auto deteccion de cambios seria una buena idea
[Best practices to improve Entity Framework performance](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2924201/microsoft-net/best-practices-to-improve-entity-framework-performance.html)

Comment: Hola Leandro, tu respuesta no debe incluir solo enlaces a recursos externos sino detallar las sugerencias directamente en la pregunta. Incluir solo enlaces no es considerado na buena respuesta. Por favor lee: [¿Como escribo una buena respuesta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Ademas de las sugerencias de Leandro, siempre revisa la traduccion del Query a SQL, a veces parece que tenemos un query muy sencillo pero al traducirlo a SQL termina siendo muy largo e ineficiente.

Ademas, si te encuentras formulando un query super largo y complicado, detente y reflexiona, tal vez no necesites un query de EF, tal vez necesites un Stored Procedure.

Mi consejo es, utiliza el sentido comun y no quieras realizar TODO con Entity framework, ese fue mi error.